# Prevent duplicates in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a column in a data table which has entries in non-decreasing order. But there can be duplicate entries.

```
labels <- c(123,123,124,125,126,126,128)
time <- data.table(labels,unique_labels="")
time
  labels unique_labels
1:    123              
2:    123              
3:    124              
4:    125              
5:    126              
6:    126              
7:    128
```

I want to make all entries unique, so the output will be

```
time
      labels unique_labels
1:    123     123           
2:    123     124         
3:    124     125         
4:    125     126         
5:    126     127         
6:    126     128         
7:    128     130
```

Following is a loop implementation for this:

```
prev_label <- 0
unique_counter <- 0
for (i in 1:length(time$label)){
    if (time$label[i]!=prev_label)
        prev_label <- time$label[i]
    else
        unique_counter <- unique_counter + 1
    time$unique_label[i] <- time$label[i] + unique_counter
}
```

Comment: googled the title of your question and got: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6759/removing-duplicated-rows-data-frame-in-r

Comment: @marcusshep I do not want to remove duplicate entries as such. Just edit them to "unduplicate " and looking for an elegant R way to avoid loops

Comment: Btw, initializing to `""` has no benefits except possibly forcing your column to contain strings.

Comment: Ok, but it's not clear the replacing rule... I mean why `123` -> `124` and `128` -> `130`?

Comment: @BrunoZamengo There is no rule as such. I have provided one possible solution to get the non-decreasing unique output. If some solution results in 128-> 129 (as long as 129 is not in the table) that's fine too.

Comment: `first(DT$label) + 1:nrow(DT) - 1L`?

Comment: @Frank it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a vectorized solution that completly prevents you from using `for` loops.
Since `time` is a `R` function I've changed the name of your `data.frame` to `tm`.

```
cumsum(duplicated(tm$labels)) + tm$labels
[1] 123 124 125 126 127 128 130

tm$unique_labels <- cumsum(duplicated(tm$labels)) + tm$labels
tm
   labels unique_labels
1:    123           123
2:    123           124
3:    124           125
4:    125           126
5:    126           127
6:    126           128
7:    128           130
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tank = ("t", 1:NROW(labels), sep="")
time$unique_labels = ifelse(duplicated(time), tank, time$labels)
```

the `duplicated` function of the `data.table` package returns the index of duplicated rows of your dataset, just replace them with "random" values you are sure are not used in your set